# Show that $[(P→Q)∧P)]→Q$ is a tautology using rules of replacement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

> Show that $[(P→Q)∧P)]→Q$ is a tautology using rules of replacement

I've done this so far,

- from $[(P→Q)∧P)]→Q$ to $[(~P∧Q)∧P)]→Q$ by Mat. Imp.
- to $[P∧(~P∧Q))]→Q$ by Commutation.

After that I'm thinking of using distribution although I'm not so sure what the result will be.

Comment: I've done this so far,                                                                    [(P→Q)∧P)]→Q
[(~P∧Q)∧P)]→Q Mat. Imp.
[P∧(~P∧Q))]→Q Commutation. after that I'm thinking of using distribution although I'm not so sure what the result will be.

Comment: Your formula for the implication is incorrect. But since you said you want to use distributivity after that, I presume it was a typing error. Anyway if you don't know what the result will be, do it and see for yourself!

Comment: @Acesd  Please click the edit button, then add your work to the question and indicate where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

One approach:
\begin{align}
[[(P \Rightarrow Q) \land P] \Rightarrow Q] &\Leftrightarrow [[(\lnot P \lor Q) \land P] \Rightarrow Q] \\
&\Leftrightarrow [[(\lnot P \lor Q) \land (\lnot (\lnot P))] \Rightarrow Q] \\
&\Leftrightarrow [Q \Rightarrow Q]
\end{align}

which is an easily verifiable tautology.